# Keep table rows intact and randomize in which column they go

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table. The left column is a word in English, on the right the same word in Korean. How can I keep the rows intact, and then randomize the order of the columns? Example:

```
<table>
<colgroup>
  <col width="*" />
  <col width="*" />
</colgroup>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>turn</td>
    <td><strong>설정하다</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>turn aside, turn around</td>
    <td><strong>옆으로 비키다</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>turn around</td>
    <td><strong>옆을보다</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>hear / listen</td>
    <td><strong>듣다</strong></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: So you want to randomize what comes first, Korean or English? [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

**update**: shuffling the `tr`s

```
var
  trs = document.querySelectorAll('tr'),
  i = trs.length,
  tr;

for (; i > 1; i -= 1) {
  tr = trs.item(Math.floor(Math.random() * i));
  tr.parentNode.appendChild(tr);
}
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/ogemec/1/

Comment: Hi! No, I don't want to randomize what comes first! Left should always be English and right always Korean. If someone studies the words, it's not good for their learning if the words are always in the same order, so I want to randomize which row is displayed first, 2nd, etc.

I understand all the Math.random options but I don't know how to work with tables and keep the rows intact (I'm new to HTML5 but not Javascript). So I haven't tried anything, just thought about it :)